# How to appendTo React Components as simple as jQuery can

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, append

As I try to get into React I find I'm running through lists of things I can do very simply in jQuery but are an absolute nightmare in React.

https://codepen.io/PocketNinjaDesign/pen/boJoEd

> have modified the goal from 2 elements to nth

The goal is that nth elements on the page can popup inside of any element / component I want on the page. I achieve this the good old fashion way by adding a data attribute containing Json with an array of components to appendTo.

You can also use JS to turn a component into a ninja and passing an object through containing the list of components to appear in.

```
$(function() {
  $('.other-ninja').Ninja({
    components: ['title', 'header', 'angry']
  });
});
```

So, imagining these are React Components now, all different kinds of components,  but the ninja block(s) can be told they can appear in any components they want.

How is that possible with React without going through a ball ache of declaration and indigestion?

Here is my code for the jQuery popup appendTo script as what I want to achieve in React.

> Have altered the code since the answer I received as I don't think I
>   was putting my question across correctly.

HTML

```
<div class="ninja" data-ninja='{"components": ["title", "happy", "sad", "stinky", "header", "AnotherComponent"]}'></div>
<div class="mongoose" data-ninja='{"components": ["happy", "sad", "stinky", "angry", "footer"]}'></div>
<div class="other-ninja"></div>

<h1 class="title">Getting React to work like simple jQuery :-D</h1>
<p>Where ALL HTML elements on this page represent React Components.  All components being
split into different files and imported using babel es6 compiler</p>
<div class="header">
  <div class="angry"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li>Just a list showing more component depth</li>
    <li>
      <div class="someOtherComponent">
        <div class="sad"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>Trying to show the code works regardless of where the elements are</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="AnotherComponent">
    <div class="SomeOtherComponent">
      <div class="WhatAnotherComponent"><div class="happy"></div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="whatever">
    <div class="stinky"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

> Removed the SCSS as it was detracting from the main focus of markup and javascript

Script

```
$(function() {
  function Ninja(e, options) {
    var $this = $(e);
    options = $.extend({}, $this.data('ninja'), options);
    var componentList = options.components;

    setInterval(function() {
      var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * componentList.length);
      $this.appendTo('.' + componentList[randomNum]);
    }, 1000);
  }

  $.fn.Ninja = function(options) {
    $(this).each(function(i, e) {
      Ninja(e, options);
    });
  };

  $('[data-ninja]').each(function(i, e) {
    $(e).Ninja();
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('.other-ninja').Ninja({
    components: ['title', 'header', 'angry']
  });
});
```

Comment: As one of the answer states, it's only a 'nightmare' because you're forcing jquery-style logic when you should be thinking about your code from a completely different perspective.

Comment: Yes i agree in a way,  but as a design requirement of a component that needs to be able to appear in any component on the page how would you go about doing it in react, in theory.  I have given a basic example using jQuery, but as the requirement is within a React setup what is the theory behind how it would work.  No need to write a load of code to answer this, just snippets of the around about area of focus, like redux or whatever. thank you :-)

Comment: based on the other comments,  if we were all sat in a company meeting room right now,  I would say, "Lets not talk about the differences between jQuery and React and the whys and wherefors.  The question is, can we get a ninja component to appear in any component anywhere on the page, dynamically without declaration on those components.  It's been shown in jQuery, is it doable in React or should we call it a day?" That is how the meeting would be. :-P

Answer (score 0):

React might seem like *"nightmare"* when you used to use jQuery but actually using React is really easy. You just need to adjust your coding logic to suit React guidelines.

The code you shared can be implemented in React many different ways. I did a small [working version](https://codesandbox.io/s/y0v196zzn9) for you to compare. At first-look it might seem a lot more code to achieve same simple affect but React has a lot more control over the DOM (Virtual DOM) and can be manipulated a lot more different ways. Most of the code in this example is same for all components. You just need to put consideration `render` method. Appending or removing a component/element can be achieved by just a simple `if` statement. Also component logic gives you a big flexibility and re-usability. There are a lot of good examples and tutorials online that can show you how you can solve thing in react way. A really good start point is [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) and [awesome-react](https://github.com/enaqx/awesome-react).

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const styles = {
  component: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  },
  happy: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    top: 100,
    left: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow'
  },
  sad: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    top: 20,
    left: 180,
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  },
  angry: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    top: 160,
    left: 500,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  stinky: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    top: 210,
    left: 300,
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  },
  ninja: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 100,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#000'
  },
  deathstar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 100,
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#444'
  }
};

const Ninja = () => (<div style={styles.ninja}></div>);
const DeathStar = () => (<div style={styles.deathstar}></div>);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      types: ['happy', 'sad', 'angry', 'stinky'],
      ninja: 0,
      deathstar: 0
    };
    this.intervalNinja = null;
    this.intervalDeathstart = null;
  }

  randomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalNinja);
    clearInterval(this.intervalDeathstart);
    this.intervalNinja = null;
    this.intervalDeathstart = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalNinja = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        ninja: this.randomNumber()
      });
    }, 1082);
    this.intervalDeathstart = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        deathstar: this.randomNumber()
      });
    }, 987);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.types.map((type, index) => (
          <div style={styles[type]}>
            {this.state.ninja === index && <Ninja />}
            {this.state.deathstar === index && <DeathStar />}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for taking the time to write all of that. I see the angle you've come from and I should have made my markup structure a little more complex to show the actual issue I have with React. The thing with my jQuery version is that the elements could be anywhere or anything with zero change to the jQuery code.  Also the elements don't even have to know that the ninjas are even there.  I'll add my code changes to the question.

Comment: First of all your welcome. Please don't get me wrong. My intention is not proving you that React is better or something. I'm not comparing the 2. Just trying to show you an example of the difference. 2 framework have different approaches on solutions. If you are still comfortable with jQuery you should use that. I was just trying to show you that before making your decision give some time and reading on it.

Comment: My issue is the same as most others, having to learn React and Angular because that is where the jobs are.  As I come straight from Macromedia Direct and Flash over 18 years ago,  jquery just worked out perfect for doing interfaces and game like UI.  So the best way I can figure out how to learn React / Angular is to try and do things I would normally do.  Which is this particular case scenario :-)

I've altered the code above and also added a commented stating the change since the first answer. thank you.

Comment: I would build a Higher Order Component (HOC) that renders these Ninja elements, and export all components that could support Ninjas wrapped in that HOC. The HOC could act as a controller (decide when and where to show Ninjas) or be driven by application state (i.e. Redux). The result is that you have as many components as you want where Ninjas CAN appear and you just worry about the logic of where they WILL appear. React forces your code to be more declarative (i.e. "this element supports some stuff appearing in it") vs jQuery ("anything goes!")

Comment: Although trying to do same things is a good approach, first trying to see how things work with that particular framework is the way to go. Of course this is my own opinion. Like I said before, I could get the same result with a lot more complicated and dynamic coding. React and Angular has lots of great features that adds them a great future. That is why I believe new "jobs" require them. Like I said before, you just need to try understand the way things work with them. Like you did years before, you might need to do another transition to the newer technology

Comment: yes indeed,  but there has to be a sweet spot thing to do in React that can cater for this issue I have :-)  I've changed the Javascript to cater for targeting directly at any element you want and turning that into a ninja as well.  To point at any element of the page and append the ninja to it.  Will update the code now.

Comment: This is the problem I'm trying to tell. You are still thinking like jQuery. You try to change any element in code. React doesn't work like that. You need to change your logic to be more react way.

Comment: So i'm doing this in jQuery and trying to do it in React, but the key to this is that it a design requirement I am discussing really.  With the focus of doing it React.  The design requirement is that I want to have a component appear within any components on the screen. 01binary, yes I've seen the possibility of redux with this solution as you put it with HOC,  but in your opinion with the declatative, it means you would have to declare all "Global" components with Every component.

Comment: The other thing is, there could be a 100 ninja's kicking off in all the components.  So declaring each one would be NUTS :-P